# How to make GUI work in web browser?

Tags: java, html, user-interface, applet, jframe

I am writing a program for my school final project. I wrote the whole project with frames, only to find out it needs to be an applet. So I tried converting everything but it does not work.

Source Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.applet.Applet;
public class AlteredBattleship extends Applet implements ActionListener{
  int ro;//holds row input
  int co;//holds column input
  int[][] shots=new int[10][10];//holds all shots taken
  boolean displayLose=false;//boolean triggers if game is lost
  boolean displayWin=false;//boolean triggers if game is won
  //the next six variables hold how many parts of ships haven't been hit
  int two=2;
  int three=3;
  int four=4;
  int threeTwo=3;
  int five=5;
  //boolean triggers if a boat is sunk
  boolean twoSunk=false;
  boolean threeSunk=false;
  boolean threeTwoSunk=false;
  boolean fourSunk=false;
  boolean fiveSunk=false;
  //holds difficulty
  boolean b=true;
  boolean n=false;
  boolean e=false;
  ArrayList<Integer> misses= new ArrayList<Integer>();//holds all missed  shots
  ArrayList<Integer> hits= new ArrayList<Integer>();//holds all hit shots
  int shotCount=75;//how many shots player has to win
  int[][] board=new int[10][10];//holds all ship positions
  JApplet main =new JApplet();//holds all graphics
  TextField input=new TextField(2);//takes input from player
  TextField count=new TextField(2);//displays shots left
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
  };
  //places the four long ship
  public void placeFour(){
    int fourStartx=(int)(Math.random()*5);
    int fourStarty=(int)(Math.random()*9);
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
      board[fourStartx+i][fourStarty]=4;
    }
  }
  //places the three long ship
  public void placeThree(){
    int threeStartx=(int)(Math.random()*9);
    int threeStarty=(int)(Math.random()*6);
    if(board[threeStartx][threeStarty]==0&& board[threeStartx][threeStarty+1]==0&&board[threeStartx][threeStarty+2]==0){
      board[threeStartx][threeStarty]=3;
      board[threeStartx][threeStarty+1]=3;
      board[threeStartx][threeStarty+2]=3;
    }
    else
      this.placeThree();
  }
  //places the two long ship
  public void placeTwo(){
    int twoStartx=(int)(Math.random()*7);
    int twoStarty=(int)(Math.random()*9);
    if(board[twoStartx][twoStarty]==0&& board[twoStartx+1][twoStarty]==0){
      board[twoStartx][twoStarty]=2;
      board[twoStartx+1][twoStarty]=2;
    }
    else
      this.placeTwo();
  } 
  //places the second three long ship
  public void placeThreeTwo(){
    int threeStartx=(int)(Math.random()*6);
    int threeStarty=(int)(Math.random()*9);
    if(board[threeStartx][threeStarty]==0&& board[threeStartx+1][threeStarty]==0&&board[threeStartx+2][threeStarty]==0){
      board[threeStartx][threeStarty]=6;
      board[threeStartx+1][threeStarty]=6;
      board[threeStartx+2][threeStarty]=6;
    }
     else
       this.placeThreeTwo();
  }
  //places the five long ship
  public void placeFive(){
    int twoStartx=(int)(Math.random()*9);
    int twoStarty=(int)(Math.random()*4);
    if(board[twoStartx][twoStarty]==0&& board[twoStartx][twoStarty+1]==0&& board[twoStartx][twoStarty+2]==0&& board[twoStartx][twoStarty+3]==0&& board[twoStartx][twoStarty+4]==0){
      board[twoStartx][twoStarty]=5;
      board[twoStartx][twoStarty+1]=5;
      board[twoStartx][twoStarty+2]=5;
      board[twoStartx][twoStarty+3]=5;
      board[twoStartx][twoStarty+4]=5;
    } 
    else 
      this.placeFive();
  } 
  //this method creates the frame and builds the interactable parts of the GUI
  public void init() {
    main = new JApplet();
    DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
    main.add(drawPanel);
    JPanel holder=new JPanel();
    JPanel line=new JPanel();
    JPanel space=new JPanel();
    space.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50,150));
    space.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
ButtonGroup level=new ButtonGroup();//holds all difficulty radioButtons
JRadioButton beginner = new JRadioButton();//beginner difficulty button
beginner.setSelected(true);
beginner.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
beginner.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //makes the button set difficulty to beginner
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent i) { 
  b=true;
  n=false;
  e=false;
} 
});
space.add(beginner);//adds button to panel
JRadioButton normal = new JRadioButton();//normal difficulty button
normal.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
space.add(normal);//adds button to panel
normal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //makes the button set difficulty to normal
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent i) { 
  b=false;
  n=true;
  e=false;
} 
});
JRadioButton expert = new JRadioButton();
expert.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
expert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//makes the button set difficulty to expert 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent i) { 
  b=false;
  n=false;
  e=true;
} 
});
space.add(expert);//adds button to panel
level.add(beginner);
level.add(normal);
level.add(expert);
count.setEditable(false);
count.setText(Integer.toString(shotCount));
line.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(105,100));
line.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
line.add(count);
holder.setLayout(new BoxLayout(holder, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));//creates panel that holds all other panels
holder.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20,50));
JPanel inputHold=new JPanel();//creates panel that holds input textField
inputHold.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(40,100));
inputHold.add(input);//adds textField to panel
//makes input take shot and put it through program
input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
  String row=input.getText().substring(0,1);//makes the first letter of input the row
  String column=input.getText().substring(1,input.getText().length());//makes number portion column
  ro=row.compareTo("A");//makes row a number representation
  co=Integer.parseInt(column)-1;//makes the String into int
  if(row.compareTo("A")<10 && Integer.parseInt(column)<=10&&shots[ro][co]==0){//makes sure shot is in bounds and not already called
    if(board[ro][co]==0){//checks for miss
      misses.add(ro);
      misses.add(co);
    }
    else{//makes sure it's a hit
      hits.add(ro);
      hits.add(co);
      if(board[ro][co]==2){//checks if hit is two ship
        two--;
        if (two==0)//checks to see if two is sunk
          twoSunk=true;
      }
      else if(board[ro][co]==3){//checks if hit is three ship
        three--;
        if (three==0)//checks to see if three is sunk
          threeSunk=true;
      }
      else if(board[ro][co]==6){//checks if hit is other three ship
        threeTwo--;
        if(threeTwo==0)//checks if other three ship is sunk
          threeTwoSunk=true;
      }
      else if(board[ro][co]==4){//check if hit is four ship
        four--;
        if (four==0)//check if four ship is sunk
          fourSunk=true;
      }
      else if(board[ro][co]==5){//check if hit is five ship
        five--;
        if(five==0)//check if five ship is sunk
          fiveSunk=true;
      }
    }
    shotCount--;//takes away a shot
    shots[ro][co]=1;//remembers spot as an already taken shot
  }
  if(twoSunk&&threeSunk&&fourSunk&&threeTwoSunk&&fiveSunk){//checks for win status
    displayWin=true;
  }
  input.setText("");//resets textField
  //frame.repaint();//resets board with new shot
  count.setText(Integer.toString(shotCount));//resets shotCount to new number
  if(shotCount==0){//checks for lose status
    displayLose=true;
    input.setEditable(false);
  }

} 
});
JPanel spacer=new JPanel();
JButton newB=new JButton("New Game");//creates new game button
newB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //makes button work
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent i) {
  //resets all variables to new game status
  displayLose=false;
  displayWin=false;
  twoSunk=false;
  threeSunk=false;
  threeTwoSunk=false;
  fourSunk=false;
  fiveSunk=false;
  two=2;
  three=3;
  threeTwo=3;
  four=4;
  five=5;
  misses= new ArrayList<Integer>();
  hits= new ArrayList<Integer>();
  if(b)
    shotCount=75;
  else if(n)
    shotCount=65;
  else if(e)
    shotCount=50;
  count.setText(Integer.toString(shotCount));
  board=new int[10][10];
  shots=new int[10][10];
  placeFour();
  placeThree();
  placeThreeTwo();
  placeFive();
  placeTwo();
  main.repaint();
} 
});
//adds all panels to frame
spacer.add(newB,BorderLayout.NORTH);
spacer.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
inputHold.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
spacer.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
spacer.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,32));
holder.add(space,BorderLayout.NORTH);
holder.add(line,BorderLayout.NORTH);
holder.add(inputHold, BorderLayout.NORTH);
holder.add(spacer,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
holder.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
main.add(holder,BorderLayout.EAST);
main.setVisible(true);
//places ships
this.placeFour();
this.placeThree();
this.placeTwo();
this.placeThreeTwo();
this.placeFive();
  }
```

And my html is:
    `<EMBED 
       type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.2"
       code="AlteredBattleship.class"
       WIDTH=680 HEIGHT=400>
   </EMBED>`

I'm sorry if the answer is really obvious I am fairly new to Java and extremely new to graphics.
Thank you for your time

Comment: Don't use applets, they are deprecated in Java 1.9 and they will be removed from Java 1.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake.

```
 public class AlteredBattleship extends Applet implements ActionListener
```

should be:

```
public class AlteredBattleship extends JApplet implements ActionListener
```

If the Applet still doesn't works, please inform.

Comment: It is very likely that I may make a mistake. I don't know what is the DrawPanel class.

Comment: It does work thank you. Sorry i did not include drawPanel I did not believe it to be relevant

Comment: I am happy to help.